# Creando una Django API, aparece el error Field 'id' expected a number but got <object>

Tags: python, django, django-models, djangorestframework

> TypeError at /api/todos/
> Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f81c50daa60>.

Tengo básicamente este error. Cuando intento ir a la path descrita debería ver la interfaz de Django RestFramework pero solamente la puedo visualizar siempre y cuando esté logeado con mi usuario en el /admin.

En este caso si no estoy logeado debería aparecer la interfaz de DRF y en el detalle del json debería decirme que mis credenciales de autenticación no fueron provistos.

Adjunto mi código que ha sido poco por ahora:

models.py en mi folder todo

```
    from turtle import title
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
    # Create your models here.
    class Todo (models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        memo = models.TextField(blank=True)
    
        #set to current time
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
        #user who created the todo
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

views.py   en folder api

```
    from rest_framework import generics, permissions
    from .serializers import TodoSerializers
    from todo.models import Todo
    
    # Create your views here.
    class TodoListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
      #ListAPIView requires two mandatory attributes: queryset and serializer_class
      #We especify TodoSerializer which we have earlier implemented
      serializer_class = TodoSerializers
    
      def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Todo.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-created')
    
    
      def perform_create(self, serializer):
        #serializer holds a django model
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
        permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

urls.py   en folder api

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    
    urlpatterns = [
      path('todos/', views.TodoListCreate.as_view()),
    ]
```

serializer.py.  in folder api

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from todo.models import Todo
    
    class TodoSerializers (serializers.ModelSerializer):
      created = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
      completed = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    
      class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'memo', 'created', 'completed']
```

urls.py   en backend folder

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('api/', include('api.urls')),
    ]
```

finalmente adjunto la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una de las cosas que realicé fue dentro del models.py en que al finalizar modifiqué el método `__str__` de este modo pero no funcionó.

```
    def __str__(self):
       return f"{self.title} owned by {self.user}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se encuentra en tu view, específicamente aquí:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    return Todo.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-created')
```

¿Qué pasa si no iniciaste sesión?
self.request.user te regresa una instancia de AnonymousUser, no de User, entonces al momento de aplicar el filtro al modelo Todo rompe, por eso funciona cuando iniciaste sesión, pero no cuando no hay un usuario logeado.

Una manera de solucionarlo es restringir el view solo a usuarios que ya iniciaron sesión agregando un permission_classes de esta manera:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class TodoListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
  #ListAPIView requires two mandatory attributes: queryset and serializer_class
  serializer_class = TodoSerializers

  permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Otra manera es que cheques si el usuario inicio sesión para poder aplicar el filtro, si no entonces regresar un queryset vacío, esto se puede lograr modificando tu método get_queryset(), algo así:

```
def get_queryset(self):
  user = self.request.user
  if user.id:
    # tiene id, el usuario inicio sesion
    return Todo.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-created')
  else:
    # Id es None, entonces no es un usuario logeado
    return Todo.objects.none()
```

Si mi respuesta te fue de ayuda te invito a marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: mil gracias kevin realmente como lo habias visto importe permissions de rest_framework lo cual creo estaba mal ya que la libreria que otorga es rest_framework.permissions para importar IsAuthenticated